# javascript <object> has #document child in DOM inspector, but has childElementCount=0

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

I'm trying to mash a proof of concept together and have the following rough code snippet in there...

```
var jenkinsBuilds = [
    {url:"http://jenkins.server:8080/view/project/job/build_type1/", x:100, y:100},
    {url:"http://jenkins.server:8080/view/project/job/build_type2/", x:200, y:200}
];

function createBuild(buildData) {

    var divBuild = document.createElement("div");
    divBuild.className = "buildNode";
    divBuild.title = buildData.url;
    divBuild.style.left = buildData.x + "px";
    divBuild.style.top = buildData.y + "px";
    backdrop.appendChild(divBuild);

    var obj = document.createElement("object");
    obj.onload = loadedObj;
    obj.type = "text/html";
    obj.data = buildData.url + "api/json?tree=builds[number]";
    divBuild.appendChild(obj);
}

function loadedObj(e) {
    alert(e.srcElement);
}
```

The alert comes up with `[object HTMLObjectElement]`.

I'm wanting to get the json contents of the object into a `var json =` variable to do a JSON.parse() on later, but I don't know how to get the json contents out of the object.

When I look at the object in the Chrome DOM inspector, it has...

```
<div>
   L <object>
        L #document
             L <html>
                  L <head></head>
                  L <body>
                       L <pre>
                            "{"builds":[{"number":3431},{"number":3430},{"number":3429},{"number":3428},{"number":3427}]}"
                         </pre>
```

So I can see the json contents in the innerText of the  node in the inspector.

But - the `<object>` has `childElementCount: 0` and the #document has `ownerDocument: null` and `parentNode: null` - so how can I get access to the `<pre>`'s json `innerText`?

I would prefer to use plain javascript rather than jQuery if possible (for ease of maintainability if I get hit by a truck).

This is not intended for public use, and will be run on the latest browsers (99% Chrome and Firefox).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the `<object>` that you include has a different domain that your main code, and you fall prey to [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).
You can't access another domain from the browser unless you can edit the other domain and set up [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) or run Chrome with `--disable-web-security` option.

Comment: Thanks for your help Denis - but I can see all the raw json contents I've sourced from our Jenkins server on the page's <div> which holds the <object>, I just can't figure out how to access it within the javascript. I'll read up on your suggestions though, cheers.

Comment: Thanks Denis - after hitting my head against the SOPolicy for another two days I have finally given up. Without access to the other domain and --disable-web-security not making any difference, I've resigned to the fact this is beyond me.